# Facing issues in Python to MYSQL insertion

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I've tried to use couple of methods to insert data into mysql database but getting error in all:
In the first method:

```
sql = ('''Insert into lgemployees (EmpID,Name,Gender,DOB,Address,PhoneNumber,Email)        
 VALUES (%d,$s,$s,$s,$s,$d,$s)''', (eid, name, gen, dob, add, mob, email))

mycursor.execute(sql)
mycursor.commit()
```

**Error in this approach:**

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

**2nd method:**

```
sql = "Insert into lgemployees (EmpID,Name,Gender,DOB,Address,PhoneNumber,Email)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)"
val =  (eid, name, gen, dob, add, mob, email)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mycursor.commit()
```

**Error in this approach** :

```
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

I've troubleshooted a lot from my end but no luck. Can any one please help as where am I wrong or what else can be a good option to insert data into mysql from python.

Comment: Also you can look here:
https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/

Comment: In the first approach you are writing `$s` instead of `%s`

Comment: @vidriduch The extra comma in the end was given in one of the articles only :). Although I've tried removing that extra comma as well. but no luck same error.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know where you error is at, but ive tested with this code and it works.

```
        insert_tuple = (eid, name, gen, dob, add, mob, email)
        sql = """INSERT INTO lgemployees (`EmpID `, 
        `Name`,`Gender`, `DOB`, `Address`, `PhoneNumber`, `Email`)
        VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        mycursor = mySQLconnection.cursor()
        mycursor.execute(sql, insert_tuple)
        mySQLconnection.commit()
        mycursor.close()
```

your code throws this because one of the parameters are empty or are in a format it cant read.

```
  "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
    mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: Thanks its working now after using all %s in all fields.. But why does it gives that error when I use %d where columns are expressed as INT in mysql. Ideally %d and %s should be used depending on INT of varchar.